# Calculate threshold that minimizes the average risk.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a two-class one dimensional problem the probability density functions are Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\mathcal{N}(1,\sigma^2)$, for the two classes. Calculate the threshold $x_0$ that minimizes the average risk. Assume that $\lambda_{11} = \lambda_{22} = 0$.

Comment: What does $\lambda_{11}=\lambda_{22}=0$ mean in this context ?

Comment: What is the risk/loss function here?

Comment: You may to explain the question in detail.  I went and searched for the lambdas in internet and I hit the solution.  https://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~jcorso/t/2011S_555/files/homework1-solutions.pdf.  Try the problem yourself first and if you are unsuccessful, then go the solution